# Why does Outlook 2016 show my user name as (pseudo?) chinese characters?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, exchange-2010, microsoft-outlook-2016

From time to time, when a nightly reboot of our Exchange 2010 server occurs, my co-worker sees this Outlook login screen in the morning:

[image]
*(His Windows login name is displayed in chinese)*

He leaves his computer and Outlook running through the night and gets the above dialog box (in German) in the morning.

On my computer, same OS, same Outlook version, my name is correctly displayed.

We did intensive virus scanning and the like, without any results.

**My question:**

What is the reason that the login name in the Outlook dialog is shown as (pseudo?) chinese characters?

And how can I fix it?

Comment: I'd guess a case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake though it doesn't match experiments here.

Comment: Does he have any Asian language on his computer?

Comment: @Scorpion99 Just checked, unfortunately not.